# how to fail Laravel validate if extra param pass to it?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rule

I'm using Laravel validation for validate user request.
it's work for me but I need to validation failed if user send any parameter more than that mentioned in rules.
for example if the rule is like this:

```
['id'=>'required|integer']
```

if user send anything extra like

```
'name'=>'foo'
```

the validation should failed and the error message is something like:

```
the name param is not allowed.
```

Comment: see this http://aaronsaray.com/2017/laravel-validate-parameter-not-present also, what is your purpose for this?

Comment: the purpose is user not send any extra key-value param to api.

Comment: in your application, is it alright if there is extra key-value but it won't be saved? or you really need to return an error whenever it happens?

Comment: i need to return error if it happen.

Comment: I don't see a use for this? If they pass extra parameters to an API it will just be ignored like any other API?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom validation rule or you can do

```
if(!in_array("name", $request->all())){
    return redirect()->back()->with('errorMessage','the name param is not allowed.')->withInput();
}
```

and to show an error message in blade file

```
@if (session('errorMessage'))
    {{ session('errorMessage') }}
@endif
```